# RPi4 - pigs bscx SPI slave not working

Tags: pi-4, spi, pigpio

I have an ESP32 set to an SPI Master with 100kHz, Mode 2 and just want to send 0x19 to the RPi4 as a slave running pigpiod and using shell for output.
When I use piscope, everything seems fine for me on the pins:

[image: PiscopeScreenshot]

But `pigs bscx 0x213` or also `pigs bscx 0x21B` always just returns `1  18` so an empty buffer.

From RPi Perspective the connections are as following:

- CE0: GPIO 8 - Pin24 ->> ESP32 - GPIO 5 (CS)
- MISO: GPIO 9 - Pin23 ->> ESP32 - GPIO 23 (MOSI)
- MOSI: GPIO 10 - Pin 19 -- not connected
- SCLK: GPIO 11 - Pin23 ->> ESP32 - GPIO 18 (SCLK)

What could be wrong?
I had it once working yesterday, but kind of unstable. I do not know what I could have changed, but now nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by changing the ESP32 sending to 2 bytes.
The examples from https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigs.html#BSCX are working so the issue must be within the ESP32 sending.

Important: BSC-MISO is GPIO 10 and not GPIO9 in "slave" mode. My wiring was wrong.